# Measurability in the product space

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g: (X,\mathscr{F}) \to (Y,\mathscr{G})$ be measurable functions, where $Y$ is a metric space. Let $A$ be a measurable set in $\mathscr{G} \otimes \mathscr{G}$. Is it true that
$$
\{x \in X: (f(x),g(x)) \in A\} \in \mathscr{F}?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{E}\equiv\{A\in\mathscr{G}\otimes\mathscr{G}| \{x\in X:(f(x),g(x))\in A\}\in\mathscr{F}\}$. Then when $A=E\times F$, $\{x\in X| (f(x),g(x))\in E\times F\}=f^{-1}(E)\cap g^{-1}(F)\in \mathscr{F}$. Moreover, it is easy to see $\mathscr{E}$ is a monotone class. Hence $\mathscr{E}=\mathscr{G}\otimes\mathscr{G}$.